# TZInfo::InvalidTimezoneIdentifier with rails 3.1.0 and ubuntu

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, ruby-on-rails-3.1

Here is the error in log file when making initial http connection to the server. It is odd that sometime the server can render a http connection without any problem. But more often with the TZinfo error.

```
Started GET "/" for 98.206.231.173 at 2011-11-13 09:41:34 +0800
  Processing by SessionsController#new as HTML
Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/sessions (2.2ms)
Completed 200 OK in 4ms (Views: 3.4ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)

TZInfo::InvalidTimezoneIdentifier (no such file to load -- tzinfo/definitions/Etc/UTC):
```

Any suggestion to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

how do you serve your Rails application? Mongrel? Unicorn? ...? can you restart your app, to make sure that all threads have the same config?

Do you have 'tzinfo' listed as a dependency in your Gemfile?

Which version of TZinfo are you using?  Can you try to update TZInfo to the latest version?
e.g. run `bundle update`

all the newer versions of TZInfo, like 0.3.30 , have the directory `lib/tzinfo/definitions/Etc` with the `UTC.rb` definition in it as follows:

```
$ more .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p0/gems/tzinfo-0.3.30/lib/tzinfo/definitions/Etc/UTC.rb 
module TZInfo
  module Definitions
    module Etc
      module UTC
        include TimezoneDefinition

        timezone 'Etc/UTC' do |tz|
          tz.offset :o0, 0, 0, :UTC

        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

What do you see underneath your `.rvm/gems/RUBY-VERSION/gems/` directory? which TZInfo are you using? and is the UTC.rb file there? Are the permissions on the directory and the file 'world readable'?

Maybe it's related to this:

http://rubyglasses.blogspot.com/2008/05/converting-timezone-to-tzinfotimezone.html

Comment: The problem seems disappeared after choosing another city in time zone. tzinfo is 0.3.30 & 0.3.29

Comment: hmm... that's really odd.. what happens if you change your system back to UTC, and make sure all services/processes are restarted? does it re-appear?  are you sure all the gems are installed the same way in production as they are in development? e.g. compare your `Gemfile.lock` files - and also the user/permissions on the directories hosting the app-code and gem-code